# Swift Combine: PassthroughSubject UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, combine

I have the following implementation:

```
var flag = CurrentValueSubject<Bool,Never>(false)
    var flagChange = PassthroughSubject<Bool,Never>()
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        flagChange.sink { [unowned self] value in
            print("value \(value)")
            print("current value \(self.flag)")
        } receiveValue: { [unowned self] value in
            print("value received \(value)")
            self.flag.send(value)
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
```

When I execute in the playground I'm getting this error/warnings:

[image]

Any of you knows why and how can avoid it or fix it?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, and it's not a warning. It's the reported QuickLook *value* of your `myClass.flagChange.send(true)` statement. Your `let myClass = MyClass()` has a pretty weird-looking QuickLook value too. It's mysterious, for sure, but if it bothers you, don't look at it. Your code itself runs fine and the printed outputs are just what you would expect. Playgrounds are strange places, and you are using one to look at the value of a statement that doesn't really have a value. So just relax and move on.